# How to create a feature in python based on a function?

Tags: python, pandas

First time stack overflow-er here. I'm trying to create some new features for this data science project that I'm working on (categorizing bank transaction data). For instance, I have transaction categories like "Auto Payments", "Gas", "Parking", etc. and I want to create a new feature called "Car" where any category with any of those words will be given a value of 1 (and all other categories will be given a 0).

I tried to write a function for "car", but I can't figure out how to create a new feature based on the results of this function. I feel like there must be a simple way to do this, but I'm a bit new at python and having trouble figuring it out!

Here's my function for car:

```
def car():
    df.category.apply(lambda x: "Auto" in x)
    df.category.apply(lambda x: "Gas" in x)
    df.category.apply(lambda x: "Parking" in x)
    df.category.apply(lambda x: "Service & Parts" in x)
```

Here's the code for how I tried to create a new column of "car":

```
df['car'] = "1" if car==True else "0"
```

Here's what the df looks like:

```
Date  Description   Amount  Category

2017-01-02  Tacos   8.34    Restaurants
2017-01-02  Transfer to Free Checking   800.00  Transfer
2016-12-30  Shell   26.26   Gas & Fuel
2016-12-29  Sunoco  22.59   Gas & Fuel
```

Thanks! I appreciate any input that you might have.

Comment: consider tagging this question "pandas"; DataFrames are not part of Python itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas try to use vectorized methods as much as possible... In this case you can use the suite of vectorized string manipulation methods. Here is [a good tutorial on them](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) from the docs.

In particular we can use [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) which checks to see if a regular expression is inside each element of a Series. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) is the Python tutorial on regular expressions.

Because `str.contains` return a `bool` you can use [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert it to an `int` (either 0 or 1).

```
df['car'] = df['Category'].str.contains('(Auto)|(Gas)|(Parking)|(Service & Parts)').astype(int)
print(df)
```

outputs

```
         Date                Description  Amount     Category  car
0  2017-01-02                      Tacos    8.34  Restaurants    0
1  2017-01-02  Transfer to Free Checking  800.00     Transfer    0
2  2016-12-30                      Shell   26.26   Gas & Fuel    1
3  2016-12-29                     Sunoco   22.59   Gas & Fuel    1
```